# Geckofx get loaded page url

Tags: wpf, gecko, geckofx

I am using geckofx-22 in my WPF app. I want to check the current url of the page which is loaded in the geckofx control. Can't find any property for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code for WPF and place it in Geckofx-WPF GeckoWebBrowser.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="Url"/> currently displayed in the web browser.
    /// Use the <see cref="Navigate(string)"/> method to change the URL.
    /// </summary>
    [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public Uri Url
    {
        get
        {
            if (_webNav == null)
                return null;

            nsIURI locationComObject = _webNav.GetCurrentURIAttribute();
            var uri = locationComObject.ToUri();
            Xpcom.FreeComObject(ref locationComObject);
            return uri ?? new Uri("about:blank");
        }
    }
```

You can then access the url as

```
geckoWebbrowser.Url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `GeckoWebBrowser.Url`

GeckoFx uses the [nsIWebNavigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebNavigation) interface to implement this.

Comment: GeckoWebBrowser.Url there is no such property

Comment: var browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
var url = browser.Url;

Comment: Tom that is available in Winforms and not in WPF project.
So I have copied the code from the winforms code for URL to WPF and voila its working now.
Thank you for pointing me in that direction