# How to get the URL off the Gecko loaded page

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

## EDIT (Important!): This question din't make sense before, and even though I have the answer from a loong time ago I decided to update it with some acual code. Probably all comments will be irrelevant because the old post contained code that had nothing to do with the question.

I'm trying to get the URL off the current loading/loaded page in `GeckoWebBrowser`. I only have one idea on how I can get it:

```
Private Sub Browser_Navigated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles Browser.Navigated

    someLabel.Text =  GeckoWebBrowser.DocumentTitle
End Sub
```

The error I am getting is that it is not updating.

Comment: I've edited your post to try and make sense of what it is you're after. What are you using `My.Settings.History.Add()` for? What are you actually after? The URL to nagivate to as you seem to be trying that with the `.Navigate` or is that the bit of code you're stuck on? Is there not such a property like `CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), GeckoWebBrowser).Url` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263271/geckofx-get-loaded-page-url)?

Comment: Boy, thanks for the edit. I'm creating a History, its fixed now. Also, `CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), GeckoWebBrowser).Url` is because im creating TABBED webbrowser. I also say that i don't have any code.... And.. The link is for WPF so..

Comment: Out of curiosity what did you do to fix it? Might be worth posting an answer if it's a suitable answer. Unless of course you've gone a completely different way with it :)

Comment: `My.Settings.History.Add(ComboBox1.Text)` - this is the way i fixed it. Almost... I need the url to give to the ComboBox information. Then, it will be fully fixed, and the combobox will work like on normal browser.